# Scalar Multiplication with a negative number in elliptic curve

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

I want to implement scalar multiplication in which  I have to multiply a point of elliptic curve with a negative number using CRYPTOPP library, but I'm getting an error while doing this.

Am I supposed to take the mod of that negative number manually and then multiply it with the point? or is there any function which will perform that task for me?

```
ECP::Point ECP::ScalarMultiply(const Point &    a,
const Integer & e)const
```

As the parameter is integer so it should take negative value as well but it is giving an error:

> Algebra.cpp
>   CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(expBegin->NotNegative())

Comment: Why would you ever do such a thing? I'm not aware of any protocol or scheme where scalar multiplication with a negative number would occur.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to do. However, as James K Polk said, why would you need that?

Comment: You would take it mod the order of the curve group if you insisted on allowing negative scalars.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Uh, then it would not allow positive scalars anymore, or they would at least generate the same result. It's probably better to simply define part of the elements in the order of the group and assume they are negative (split the order in two, or say that anything above a certain value should be assumed negative).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I don't understand your comment. By "mod the order of the group" I meant the positive remainder after dividing by the group order.

Comment: I get what you're saying, you're saying that the negative value is equivalent to the mod value, if you see the scalar as a number. However that equivalence can come back and bite you if you're not careful. You can map integers to the elements of the group in various ways after all. You don't want an RSA signature to match *both* -1 and N - 1 if you use that as input. The way to map integers to group elements must be clear from the start.